# ng-click in <nav> tag

Tags: html, css, angularjs, web

I'm trying to add a button with `ng-click` on my header with a `<nav>` tag but as per testing of `ng-click` event, function is not triggering with the `<nav>` tag.

If I remove the `<nav>` tag its working as expected.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="nav-holder main-menu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button ng-click="scrollxx()">Checkout</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```js
$scope.scrollxx = function( ) {
    console.log("scrolltoaaaa");
}
```

Any suggestion on how to make it work?

Comment: can you share the error you get?

Comment: The ng-click event is not triggering with the <nav> tag. If I remove the <nav> tag its working as expected.

Comment: <body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="myFunc()">OK</button>
    <p>The button has been clicked {{count}} times.</p>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $scope.count++;
    };
}]);
</script>

Comment: similar like this?

Comment: Can you share your controller js file? Also, please check if the controller is properly initialized to the template.

Comment: yes its initialized since if I just remove the <nav> tag its working.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle link using your code and i was able to trigger click event even if <nav> is present. The link is https://jsfiddle.net/anilsarkar/aLmt2yg8/6/  . So this is not something related to nav.